# Python use .json as config file with class instances

Tags: python, json, class, object, config

I'm creating an application that stores it's config in a dictionary. I know I can write this to a JSON file and read this every time the app starts. But the problem is that this dictionary also contains objects. Like so(LED is an imported module with the classes APALedstrip and Arduino)

```
rooms['livingroom'] = {
    "room":data.room(name = 'livingroom',dataKeys = dataKeys),
    "lights":{
        "LedStrip":LED.APALedstrip(name = 'livingroom',
            room = 'livingroom')
        }
    }

rooms['bed'] = {
        "room":data.room(name = 'bed', dataKeys = dataKeys),
        "lights":{
            "LedStrip":LED.Arduino(name ='bed',
                serialPort = 'ttyUSB0',
                room = 'livingroom',
                master = {'room':'livingroom', 'light':'LedStrip'},
                roomSensors = 'livingroom')
            }
        }
```

I'm curious is it also possible to store this in an JSON file like so? And when it's imported into a dictionary that the objects are still created?

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize your objects. One way is to use "pickle".

Pickle convert an object to bytes, so the next step is to convert them to string using base64.

I choose base64 because it's safe for non-ASCII characters

In order to automatically save and retrieve the rooms use

> save_rooms() and retrieve_rooms()

```
import codecs
import json
import pickle


def save_rooms(rooms):
    for room in rooms:
        # find all LedStrip objects
        if 'lights' in rooms[room] and 'LedStrip' in rooms[room]['lights']:
            lights = rooms[room]['lights']['LedStrip']

            # encode object to bytes with pickle and then to string with base64
            rooms[room]['lights']['LedStrip'] = codecs.encode(pickle.dumps(lights),
                                                              "base64").decode()
    with open("rooms.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(rooms, f)


def retrieve_rooms():
    with open("rooms.json") as f:
        rooms = json.load(f)
    for room in rooms:
        # find all LedStrip objects
        if 'lights' in rooms[room] and 'LedStrip' in rooms[room]['lights']:
            lights = rooms[room]['lights']['LedStrip']

            # decode from string to bytes with base64 and then from bytes to object with pickle
            rooms[room]['lights']['LedStrip'] = pickle.loads(codecs.decode(lights.encode(), "base64"))

    return rooms


rooms = {}
rooms['livingroom'] = {
    "room": data.room(name='livingroom', dataKeys=dataKeys),
    "lights": {
        "LedStrip": LED.APALedstrip(name='livingroom',
                                    room='livingroom')
    }
}

rooms['bed'] = {
    "room": data.room(name='bed', dataKeys=dataKeys),
    "lights": {
        "LedStrip": LED.Arduino(name='bed',
                                serialPort='ttyUSB0',
                                room='livingroom',
                                master={'room': 'livingroom', 'light': 'LedStrip'},
                                roomSensors='livingroom')
    }
}
save_rooms(rooms)
loaded_rooms = retrieve_rooms()
```

In addition I implemented the logic so you can save any variation of rooms as long as you keep the structure the same.

ex.

```
rooms['kitchen'] = {
    "room": data.room(name='kitchen', dataKeys=dataKeys),
    "lights": {
        "LedStrip": LED.APALedstrip(name='kitchen',
                                    room='kitchen')
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you adding base64 encoding?

Comment: picke returns bytes so we need convert them in string, if we only store ASCII then it's unessasary, but since i have no idea what is the object i thought it's safer...

Comment: Why does it need to be converted to a string?

Comment: In order to save it as JSON file... As far as i know json only accepts unicode string. Is there a better way?

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you are proposing now, but then, you'll have to manually keep some logic around to know which keys are meant to refer to serialized bytes, you should probably point that out.

Comment: Going to try that out when I'm home again. Do I understand it correct that I need to make the dictionary with objects once and then run the save_rooms function. After that I can delete the creation of the rooms dict from the main code and only run retrieve rooms command? So that the json file is the only place where all these rooms are set?

Comment: Exactly! After calling save_rooms() you can also see the generated file "rooms.json". In addition in the key "LedStrip" you can see a long string representing your object. To read the file just call retrieve_rooms() and you are going to get your original dictionary